# What Are Collections Implemented As In VB6?

Tags: collections, vb6

So a collection in VB6 keeps track of a key for each object, and you can look up the object by its key.

Does that mean collections are implemented as some sort of hashtable under the hood?  I realize you can have multiple items with the same key in a collection, hence the SOME SORT.

Anybody know what type data structure a VB6 collection is supposed to represent?

Comment: You can **not** have multiple items with the same key in a VB6 Collection.

Comment: Have you tested this?  I will test this tommorrow...I had thought adding the same key wasn't a problem.

Comment: Adding multiple items with NO key is OK, but keys are case insensitively unique (irrespective of the Option Compare declaration).

Comment: Indeed you cannot duplicate a key in a collection, but you can add multiple copies of the same object without a key...which is weird, because if it was hashing the objects behind the scenes, wouldn't it be getting the same hash each time?  I wish I knew what the language creators intended.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, the VBA Collection is implemented as a linked list (used by Integer indexes and For Each...Next) and a hash table (used by keys).  And as Raven said, you can't have multiple items with the same key.

**Edited:**

@MarkJ: I should have given my cite for this:
Hardcore Visual Basic 2nd Ed. by Bruce McKinney, published by Microsoft Press 1997 ISBN 1-57231-422-2

Quotes:

Page 191 - The Collection Class

"To put it simply, the Collection class is a souped-up C++ version of the CList class [...].  In fact, if you enhance CList to be a doubly linked list and give it a few more features (and perhaps use a hash table to look up string keys), you'll have a collection class much like the one provided with Visual Basic."

Page 197 - Performance

"And, as a matter of fact, I have been told by Visual Basic developers that Collections are doubly linked lists (with additional features to support indexing)."

Now, McKinney was more of a journalist than a programmer, and not a developer.  However, he did work for Microsoft, and have contacts in the VB and VBA teams.  His explanation works for me.

Incidentally, the reason for the doubly-linked list is to make it efficient to insert items at both the beginning and end of the collection.

Comment: So does that mean there are both a linked list AND a hashtable existing side-by-side, holding references to the same item objects?

And depending on how you iterate it, is uses the different data structures as needed?

Comment: Mark is describing the code interface through which you access a Collection. We can only deduce that under the hood must be something that supports the functionality. We can speculate that it might use a linked list & hash table but we don't know that.

Comment: @MarkJ: I was hoping someone would be able to point me towards a resource which would clear up the speculation about the implementation.

Comment: @Tom T: I know, and my point was that this answer doesn't do it.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  I think this pretty much answers my question.