# How to give a name to each list item in Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

I am making a music player using the list control. I want to let the user change the name of the song on the list, but i want some property of **THAT** list item to contain its path.
Please help me in this. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
Private Sub AddToList(ByVal txtFileName As String)
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim blnFileAlreadyexists As Boolean
    txtFileName = Trim(txtFileName)
    If txtFileName <> "" Then
        blnFileAlreadyexists = False
        For I = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
            If Trim(List1.List(I)) = txtFileName Then
                blnFileAlreadyexists = True
            End If
        Next
        If Not blnFileAlreadyexists Then
            List1.AddItem (txtFileName)
            List1.ItemData (txtFileName)

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a *listbox*, after you add an item set its `x.itemdata(x.newindex)` to the index of an array (or UDT array) that contains the corresponding data.

For a *listview* you can similarly use an individual items `.Tag` or `.Key` to store an array (or collection) index.

**Linking a listbox example**;

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TFileData
    OriginalFilePath As String
    ListBoxIndex     As Integer
    MoreBlaBla       As String
    '//any more members
End Type

Private maFiles() As TFileData

Private Sub Form_Load()
    '//initial alloc
    ReDim maFiles(0)

    AddToList "AAAA"
    AddToList "BBBB"
    AddToList "AAAA"
    AddToList "CCCC"

    '//test by looping listbox;
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
         MsgBox List1.List(i) & " - " & maFiles(List1.ItemData(i)).OriginalFilePath
    Next

    '// a better type centric test;
    For i = 0 To UBound(maFiles) - 1
        MsgBox maFiles(i).OriginalFilePath & " - List entry: " & List1.List(maFiles(i).ListBoxIndex)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub AddToList(ByVal txtFileName As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim blnFileAlreadyexists As Boolean
    txtFileName = Trim(txtFileName)
    If txtFileName <> "" Then
        blnFileAlreadyexists = False
        For i = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
            If Trim(List1.List(i)) = txtFileName Then
                blnFileAlreadyexists = True
            End If
        Next
        If Not blnFileAlreadyexists Then
            '//add to list
            List1.AddItem (txtFileName)

            '//store the original value in the array;
            maFiles(UBound(maFiles)).OriginalFilePath = "TEST: " & txtFileName

            '//store the index of the array in the list;
            List1.ItemData(List1.NewIndex) = UBound(maFiles)

            '//or better store in the type
            maFiles(UBound(maFiles)).ListBoxIndex = List1.NewIndex

            '//increment the array for the next item;
            ReDim Preserve maFiles(UBound(maFiles) + 1)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: how do I do that, please help me with the code. I've made an edit in my question and added the code.

Comment: Added an example of associating a set of data in a type with a listbox entry

Comment: ReDim Preserve can be a killer.  Often using a Collection will be faster here.  You can add items "anonymously" (no key) and retrieve them by index instead.

Comment: @YASH: I agree with @Bob here. `ReDim Preserve` is fine for reasonably small arrays, but it gets more inefficient as you increase the number of data items, because it has to copy the entire contents of the array into a new array each time. Collections are linked lists internally, so adding an item takes the same amount of time no matter how many items you have (technically, a VB6 collection is a doubly-linked list, so insertions are fast at either end of the list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548526/what-are-collections-implemented-as-in-vb6)