# Time-complexity of read and write operations in VBA collections

Tags: vba, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of setting and retrieving a collection in VBA?

Let's say I create a dictionary. What is the Time-Complexity of adding items?

```
Dim studentHeights As New Collection()
studentHeights.Add("6.5","Jerry")
studentHeights.Add("5.5","Tom")
studentHeights.Add("5.35","Garry")
studentHeights.Add("5.85","Helvik")
```

What is the Time-Complexity of retrieving a specific item?

```
someVar = studentHeights.Item("Jerry")
```

Comment: Based on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548526/what-are-collections-implemented-as-in-vb6 implies that the time complexity would the same as adding or searching a doubly linked list and a hash table. If they implemented these sensibly, it would be O(1) average, O(n) worst case, in both cases.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4830157/11683 (note that *by index* is different to *by key*).

Comment: Use a `Dictionary` (reference the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* library) instead of a keyed `Collection`. Dictionary lookup will be O(1).

Comment: @Mat'sMug Is there any downside to using a dictionary?

Comment: Besides having to add the reference to every project that needs it? none that I can think of. Some people will say you don't need to add the reference, just declare as `Object` and use `CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` - but that's late-bound code, and late-bound code has much more overhead and performance penalty, which kinda defeats the purpose. Plus you don't get IntelliSense/Auto-Complete on late-bound code, and late-bound code needs to load the type anyway, it's not like the dictionary is magically being created out of thin air.

Comment: The only "gotcha" I can think of is that there's a potentially nasty "get or add" behavior to accessing a non-existent key.

Comment: Also you can iterate the keys of a dictionary and validate whether a key exists - these things a `Collection` cannot do.

Comment: Using a Dictionary is a problem if your code might need to run on a Mac. This https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary could be used but may have different performance.