# What is the lookup / access time complexity of VBA Dictionary?

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of VBA Dictionary lookup or access?
I couldn't find the documentation on it.

EDIT - Some comments from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621988/time-complexity-of-read-and-write-operations-in-vba-collections?noredirect=1&lq=1) suggested that it is O(1) which I think is true, however, there are no online references on it.

```
Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
dict("Apples") = 50
dict("Oranges") = 100
dict("Bananas") = 30

'lookup
dict.Exists("Apples")

'access
dict("Oranges")
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621988/time-complexity-of-read-and-write-operations-in-vba-collections?noredirect=1&lq=1   2nd hit on Googling "What is the time complexity of VBA Dictionary lookup or access"  ;-)

Comment: @TimWilliams are Collection and Dictionary same thing?

Comment: @TimWilliams according to [this](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/3391/Using-the-Dictionary-Class-in-VBA.html), they are not the same.

Comment: "Let's say I create a dictionary. What is the Time-Complexity of adding items?" Weren't you asking about dictionaries?

Comment: @TimWilliams take a look at his code, he is NOT using `dictionary`. He is using a `collection`.

Comment: Yes the OP is a bit unclear but it's worth reading the comments - eg for Mathieu's comment on performance being  O(1)

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, but I can't find the reference documentation he mentioned online. That's why I asked. I already went through that posting before asking.

Comment: I'm not finding anything definitive, but several unsourced references to retrieval being O(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object#syntax),

> *A Dictionary object is the equivalent of a PERL associative array.*

And
according to [perl documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Data%3A-Hashes-(Associative-Arrays)), `associative arrays` are called `hashes`:

> *Hashes (Associative Arrays)*

Lastly, according to this [perl documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context) states that:

> If you evaluate a hash in scalar context, it returns a false value if
>   the hash is empty. If there are any key/value pairs, it returns a true
>   value. A more precise definition is version dependent.
>
> Prior to Perl 5.25 the value returned was a string consisting of the
>   number of used buckets and the number of allocated buckets, separated
>   by a slash. This is pretty much useful only to find out whether Perl's
>   internal hashing algorithm is performing poorly on your data set. For
>   example, you stick 10,000 things in a hash, but evaluating %HASH in
>   scalar context reveals "1/16" , which means only one out of sixteen
>   buckets has been touched, and presumably contains all 10,000 of your
>   items. This isn't supposed to happen.
>
> As of Perl 5.25 the return was changed to be the count of keys in the
>   hash. If you need access to the old behavior you can use
>   Hash::Util::bucket_ratio() instead.

which implies amortized O(1) for lookup.